# Created counter ist counting twice (sometimes)

Tags: counters

I wanted to create a couter to count additional chapters (appendix of the thesis).

```
\newcounter{anhangCount}
\setcounter{anhangCount}{0}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\anhangPraeFix}{
    Anhang
    \Alph{anhangCount}:
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\anhangKapitelUndLabel}[2]{
    \addtocounter{anhangCount}{1}
    \addchap{\anhangPraeFix #1}
    \ihead{\anhangPraeFix #1}\label{#2}
}
```

In the document, I want to use it like this:

```
\anhangKapitelUndLabel{List of blablabla}{raw_list}
 %Longtable
 %blablabla
\anhangKapitelUndLabel{List of ..... }{list}
```

But in the PDF there ist simething like:

```
% Anhang A: List of blablabla
%% Anhang A: List of blablabla
%% page1 of the longtable
%----------------------------
%----------------------------
% Anhang A: List of blablabla
%% page2 of the longtable
%----------------------------
%----------------------------
% Anhang B: List of blablabla %%<-- why?
%% page3 of the longtable
%----------------------------
%----------------------------
% Anhang C: List of .....  %%<-- why?
%% Anhang C: List of ..... 
%----------------------------
```

I don't use the counter `anhangCount` anywhere else in the document. Why is the number in the header higher than in the title?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than a selection of snippets, it's generally better to create a complete, compilable code example. That way we don't have to make any assumptions about your setup, and it's less effort as we don't have to create a complete file ourselves.

Comment: No way of debugging that unless you make a complete example that shows the problem. Presumably you use the command in some context that is evaluated twice. Also you give no indication of what the commands are supposed to do, but if you want the `\label` to record your counter you need `\refstepcounter{anhangCount}` not `\addtocounter{anhangCount}{1}`

Comment: Unrelated but you are missing `%` from the ends of most of the lines of your code.

Comment: A tip from me (As a German) : Not everybody understands German here and it's better to provide English translations for your commands. And yes: The complete setup is unclear